CSV and Pandas not displaying \n, so I can't remove it, but it gets written into postgre database
I've tried debugging for an entire day but can't seem to do anything about this. Appreciate whatever help I can get!
I opened a CSV utf-8 file as a Pandas dataframe. The Corpus column contains text. I'm not sure why, but all the escaped characters (e.g. '\n') cannot be 'seen' in either the CSV file nor the Pandas dataframe.
But I know they are there, because they appear when I write them into my postgre database:
'\xa0  -\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Account Manager to obtain growth plans & projections from customer  \r\n'

This is highly annoying because I need to remove all of them in order to embed my Corpus column. However, they are nowhere to be 'seen' in my Pandas dataframe to do the usual string manipulations.
Please help :(
